# How can I sum values inside reduce with multi condition?

Tags: javascript

I want to sum up all of data base on two condition in side my reduce function.

Let's say I have data as following:

```
const data = [
{
   "id": 1,
   "option": BP,
   "result": 'win',
   "amount": 50
},
{
   "id": 3,
   "option": BP,
   "result": 'win',
   "amount": 20
},
{
   "id": 5,
   "option":VN,
   "result": 'win',
   "amount": 50
},
{
   "id": 5,
   "option":GB,
   "result": 'loss',
   "amount": 40
}
];
```

Here is my code:

```
data.reduce((newValueBetting, modelBetting) => {
      if (
        modelBetting.option === 'VN'
              && modelBetting.result === 'win'
      ) {
        newValueBetting += modelBetting.amount;
      }
      return newValueBetting;
    }, 0);
```

Regarding to this code. it will sum when my **data** is matches with condition. But, if I want to sum up **option === 'BP' && result === 'win'**. So, I don't want to write code again. Any idea? How can I make my reduce run only one time and get to this object:

```
{
  TotalBPWin: 70,
  TotalVN: 50,
  TotalGBLoss: 40
}
```

Comment: how about filter your array before use reduce ?

Comment: maybe declare `TotalBPWin`, `TotalVN`, `TotalGBLoss` first and caculate them in a for loop?

Comment: can you make it for me sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using reduce pass an object with all 3 key `TotalBPWin`, `TotalVN`, `TotalGBLoss` with initial value as `0`. Then conditionally add them together.

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    option: "BP",
    result: "win",
    amount: 50,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    option: "BP",
    result: "win",
    amount: 20,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    option: "VN",
    result: "win",
    amount: 50,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    option: "GB",
    result: "loss",
    amount: 40,
  },
];

const accumulator = {
  TotalBPWin: 0,
  TotalVN: 0,
  TotalGBLoss: 0,
};

const result = data.reduce((newValueBetting, { option, result, amount }) => {
  if (option === "VN" && result === "win") {
    newValueBetting["TotalVN"] += amount;
  } else if (option === "BP" && result === "win") {
    newValueBetting["TotalBPWin"] += amount;
  } else if (option === "GB" && result === "loss") {
    newValueBetting["TotalGBLoss"] += amount;
  }
  return newValueBetting;
}, accumulator);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use object in reduce rather than 0. The following is the simple implementation, you will probably need to refine the condition in the reduce for summation.

```js
const data = [
{
   "id": 1,
   "option": 'BP',
   "result": 'win',
   "amount": 50
},
{
   "id": 3,
   "option": 'BP',
   "result": 'win',
   "amount": 20
},
{
   "id": 5,
   "option":'VN',
   "result": 'win',
   "amount": 50
},
{
   "id": 5,
   "option":'GB',
   "result": 'loss',
   "amount": 40
}
];

let result = {
  'VN':0,
  'GB':0,
  'BP':0
};

data.reduce((acc,item) => {

  result[item.option] += item.amount

  return acc;
}, result);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This won't work if `option: "GB"` and `result: "win"`

Comment: Ya, that is why I mentioned he will probably need to refine the condition of sum in reduce to his preference.

Answer (score 0):

The following `reduce` will get you a sum of counts for each option. Importantly, if any option has zero wins, then there won't be an associated sum for it (See the log output).

```js
const data = [{id:1,option:"BP",result:"win",amount:50},{id:3,option:"BP",result:"win",amount:20},{id:5,option:"VN",result:"win",amount:50},{id:5,option:"GB",result:"loss",amount:40}];

const result = data.reduce((all, el) => {
  if (el.result === "win") {
    all[el.option] = (all[el.option] || 0) + el.amount; 
  }
  return all;
}, {});

console.log(result.BP);
console.log(result.VN);
console.log(result.GB);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a simple loop for this and no need for `if()` conditionals

```js
const data=[{id:1,option:"BP",result:"win",amount:50},{id:3,option:"BP",result:"win",amount:20},{id:5,option:"VN",result:"win",amount:50},{id:5,option:"GB",result:"loss",amount:40}];

const res= {};

data.forEach(o=>{
   const k = 'Total' + o.option + o.result
   res[k] = (res[k] || 0) + o.amount
});

console.log(res)
```